# Redis Cloud and connect-redis: the client is closed

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I currently build a website using Express and want to use redis cloud database to save userID in session. The redisClient is created in redisClient.js and after that i pass it to redisStore in session in app.js. Here is the code:

**redisCLient.js**

```
const redis = require("redis");
let redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOSTNAME,
    port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD
});

redisClient.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('*Redis Client Error: ' + err.message);
});
redisClient.on('connect', function(){
   console.log('Connected to redis instance');
});

(async () => {
    await redisClient.auth(process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD)
        .catch(err => {console.log('Redis auth error: ' + err.message)});
    await redisClient.connect()
        .catch(err => {console.log('Redis connect error: ' + err.message)});
})();

module.exports = redisClient;
```

**app.js**

```
const session = require("express-session");
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const redisClient = require('./session-store/redisClient');

...

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  store: new redisStore({client: redisClient, ttl: 3600 * 24 * 30}),
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false
}));
```

**The problem is:** upon starting the server i got error messages log in console like this:

```
Redis auth error: The client is closed
*Redis Client Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
*Redis Client Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
*Redis Client Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
*Redis Client Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
...
```

I used this [guide](https://dev.to/ramko9999/host-and-use-redis-for-free-51if) to set up redis cloud and assign dotenv variables (host, port and password). I have debugged and the dotenv is working fine and I have host, port and password variables correct.

But the problem still remains. I still get *The client is closed* and *connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379* error as in console log above. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

was stuck on same issue and found some luck. have used 'ioredis' module instead of redis which worked seamlessly.

```
const redis = require('ioredis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient({host:'your host address',port:your port,username:'',password:''});

redisClient.on('connect',() => {
    console.log('connected to redis successfully!');
})

redisClient.on('error',(error) => {
    console.log('Redis connection error :', error);
})

module.exports = redisClient;
```

Comment: Hey this works. Thank you!! May i ask why using `ioredis` module instead of `redis`? Is it the matter of compatibility or something else?

Comment: ioredis is the updated client instead of redis. I found many bugs regards to redis client hence, tried ioredis.

Answer (score 1):

You must do `await redisClient.connect()` before you access the client. Try to move your `redisClient.connect()` just after you create it.

Comment: I have moved redisCLient.connect() right after my `let redisClient = redis.createClient({...})`. The same problem is still there.

Comment: I personally faced this issue and that was the problem for me, I would suggest you to elaborate a bit more and provide logs if you have any. Try to connect to redis using cli and check if the client is up or not

Comment: I have tried to connect and the client is definitely up. And for the error logs i have provided them all in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this -->

var options = {
     client: redis.createClient({
     url : process.env.REDIS_URL,
     legacyMode: true,
})};
```

you can make your url as 'redis://host:port'

Answer (score 1):

When you create a client using `redis.createClient`, you need to use `url` instead of `host`, `port`.

refer to [basic-example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example)

it showing `url` format
`redis[s]://[[username][:password]@][host][:port][/db-number]`

in your case, it might be like this

```
var url = `redis://<YourUsername>:${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}@${process.env.REDIS_HOSTNAME}:${parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT)}`
redis.createClient({
    url: url
});
```

Using `host`, `port` option must be the old version.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: switch the order of the calls to `auth` and `connect`**

From the [Node Redis client documentation](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/v3.1.2#clientauthpassword-callback):

> When connecting to a Redis server that requires authentication, the AUTH command must be sent as the first command after connecting.

You should therefore switch the order of the calls to `redisClient.auth` and `redisClient.connect`.

**Option 2: remove the call to `auth`**

However, the [documentation for the `password` property of `createClient` options](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/v3.1.2#rediscreateclient) states:

> If set, client will run Redis auth command on connect.

As you are supplying `password` to `createClient`, you could alternatively just remove the explicit call to `auth`.

Comment: Sadly, I have tried both options but the error is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createClient } from "redis";

const redisClient = createClient({
    url: "redis://localhost:6379",
});

const start = async () => {
    await redisClient.connect();
};
start();
export default redisClient;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.